# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, robotium

I have created test project...I have updloaded junit.jar in the (Run time configuration class path --> user entries --> junit.jar

I am getting below errror when i run the code...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Are you executing the tests from within
the root of your android project (where the manifest file is)?

Comment: out side the android folder..

Answer (score 8):

You need to run it as **Android JUnit test**, instead of **JUnit test**.
Go to the project in the project explorer->right click->**Android JUnit test**

Answer (score 0):

`android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is not in the JUnit JAR that you claim to have added to classpath.

That looks like one of yours.

Did you compile the code?  If not, please do so.

Did you add the path to the location where your .class files are written?  If not, please do so.

Comment: Can you please give me how to add the class path..                          Run --> Run As --> Run configuration --> Class Path. Add Junit.jar from the eclipse folder.? is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_eclipse.html

Basically, you don't have to add `junit.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: Hi, Can you please share your mail id.. I will send you whatever i did.. I followed 
http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&qscrl=1&source=hp&q=robotium+with+apk&qscrl=1&pbx=1&oq=robotium+with+apk&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=71706l85633l0l86082l72l37l27l3l5l6l960l12650l0.13.10.4.2.2.5l50l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=2b1c1827496a067e&biw=1366&bih=643                                                                              I have added junit.jar in the eclipse and system class path...still i am getting same issue..

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. For me Changing the "Order and Export" (properties->build Path->Order and Export) of robotium-solo.jar i.e moving it to the top and explicitly selecting run as 'android JUnit test' by right clicking the project solved the problem. Also try running the [sample project](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/downloads/list) provided.

Answer (score -1):

It might sound strange. but all you need to do is import solo before you import the class and it works. At least it did for me. i dont know why i tried that but all it needed was to cut the import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo; and paste it just after the package.

Comment: It is strange and has probably nothing to do with the order of the import. The order in the file is absolutely not important because the runtime will ensure the right order.